# Class PDO not found after update from PHP 7.2.13 to PHP 7.3.0 on Debian 9

Tags: php, pdo, updates

In one server with on Debian 9, I just updated the PHP from version 7.2.13 to version 7.3.0, but now the PDO does not working.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found.
```

The libs is alread installed:

```
root@/# apt install php7.3-pdo
Reading packages list... Ready
Building dependences tree
Reading state informations... Ready
Note, selecting  'php7.3-common' instead of 'php7.3-pdo'
php7.3-common is already the newest version (7.3.0-1+0~20181206202713.23+stretch~1.gbp076afd).
0 packages updated, 0 new packages instaled, 0 packages to be removed e 0 packages  not updated.
root@/# apt install php7.3-mysql
Reading packages list... Ready
Building dependences tree
Reading state informations... Ready
php7.3-mysql is already the newest version (7.3.0-1+0~20181206202713.23+stretch~1.gbp076afd).
0 packages updated, 0 new packages instaled, 0 packages to be removed e 0 packages  not updated.
root@/#
```

The file  `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` is with `pdo_mysql` enabled.

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

The `phpinfo()` says that the file `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` is the right php.ini file used by Apache Web Server:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.2/apache2
```

The `phpinfo()` only have info about PDO at "Module Authors":

```
MySQL driver for PDO    George Schlossnagle, Wez Furlong, Ilia Alshanetsky, Johannes Schlueter
```

More info:

- Without any `.htaccess` file.
- Without any `.user.ini` file.
- The Apache2 was restarted.
- I'm using the same code that worked well with PHP version 7.2.13.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this new code, or existing code that worked before updating.  It's not very clear.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes I restarted the Apache! This is a existing code that worked well with PHP 7.2.13.